# How to install Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS in Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: xubuntu, raspberrypi

Firstly does RAP 3 even support Ubuntu Server ?

Comment: [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) is what you're looking for.

Comment: And this: https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/blog/ubuntu-pi-flavours-for-raspberry-pi-3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does ! You can donwload and copy pre-installed image of ubuntu server  16.04 for Raspberry PI

```
cd /tmp
wget http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz
```

If your sdcard path is `/dev/mmcblk0` :

```
xzcat ubuntu.img.xz | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

When exec end, your sd-card is ready to boot.
You can find more info  [there](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) as suggested by @negusp

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mkusb** to extract the compressed image file

```
ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz
```

to the card. You can get the file from

http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3

**mkusb** wraps a safety belt around **dd**: helps you select the correct drive (in this case the memory card), and it will work if the card is connected via USB and also when the card is seen as an MMC block device.

See the following link,

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb